# ansible command for checking service

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible and trying to make a simple playbook to check if a service is up.

```
service... account-daemon.service
```

part of my playbook which included this is as follows:

```
- name account daemon service get status
  command: systemctl show -p SubState account-daemon
  register: status

- debug: msg="{{ status.stout }}"
```

Please note there is no spaces between playbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as below to check the status of services, example below for rscd

```
  - name: populate service facts
    service_facts:

  - debug:
     var: ansible_facts.services

  - debug:
      msg: "service is running"
    when: ansible_facts.services['account-daemon.service'].state ==  "running"
```

Output:

> ok: [localhost] => {
>       "msg": "service is running"
>   }

Reference: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_facts_module.html

Edit:

```
  - name: check rscd
    stat:
     path: /etc/init.d/rscd
    register: serv
  - name: populate service facts
    service_facts:

  - debug:
     var: ansible_facts.services

  - debug:
      msg: "rscd is running"
    when: serv.stat.exists and ansible_facts.services['rscd.service'].state ==  "running"
```

Comment: Hi cheers for this.
Im looking at what I have put down as we speak and this is what I have got:

- name: populate service facts
  service_facts
- debug:
     var: ansible_facts.services

  - debug:
      msg: "account daemon is running"
    when: ansible_facts.services.account-daemon.services ==  "running"

Comment: Sorry Ash for that reply and not providing you enough info.

Comment: Sorry Ash for that reply and not providing you enough info. No its not working for me. I just want to check if this service (account_daemon.service) on two centos boxes. I think it is really simple but im stuggling for some reason. It's apart of lots of scripts which I have created on this playbook but this is the only one I can't get my head around.. thanks in advance if you can help anymore

Comment: should I be adding account-daemon.service where you have put RSCD?

Comment: cheers ash... no we are cooking with gas. the VAR has given me a list of services but the last part is not working... FAILED! => {msg:  "the conditional check 'anisble_facts_services['account_daemon.service']state == \ "running\")

Comment: it does say the offending line appearsto be :\n\n\n - debug:\n

Comment: I have searched to first part of data which has come back and i can confirm "accounts-daemon.service" is there! 
Running and enabled. 

Which im happy with but I just want to find that service only

Comment: yes it looks like the offending line is the last - debug

Comment: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'anisible_facts_services['account_daemon.service'].\"state\" == \"running\"' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {% if anisible_facts_services['account_daemon.service'].\"state\" == \"running\" %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to be in Desktop/ansible/accountdaemon.yaml': line 24, column 9, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n      - debug:\n        ^ here\n"}

Comment: your error shows anisible_facts_services, it is anisible_facts.services

Comment: Hi Ash, thanks for all your help so far
edited it and other mistakes and still getting an issue

Comment: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_facts.services['accounts_daemon.service'].state ==  \"running\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ansible_facts.services['accounts_daemon.service'].state ==  \"running\"): 'dict object' has no attribute 'accounts_daemon.service'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/kev/Desktop/ansible/accountdaemon.yaml': line 24, column 9, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n      - debug:\n        ^ here\n"}

Comment: can you paste the output of second debug var: ansible_facts.services. paste only the part which has your service name

Comment: all done... user error and typo on the last part!

thank you so much for you time and paitence!